# DNN jQuery conflict - pop up window won't close

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, dotnetnuke

I'm working on a DNN site that has been set up before my time here.

There's some conflict with the jQuery I believe, which prevents the modal pop up window in the attached calendar (link) events to not close properly:

http://www.sim-one.ca/NewsandEvents/calendar-of-events.aspx

I tried eliminating one script call at a time to see which one could be messing this up to no avail.

When I test this with the default theme it works like a charm.

Any ideas? Anyone came across something like this before?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You've got plenty of 404 errors on that page, ensure first, that files are in their place.
For example, http://www.sim-one.ca/NewsandEvents/Portals/_default/Skins/SimTwo/includes/js/jquery.listnav-2.1.js was not found. Ensure this path exists.

Comment: That's odd. I checked that path and the file is there on the live root. I'll double check if this copy I'm checking is the live one. thank you for your help man.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Anrie that your references are broken. For example, `http://www.sim-one.ca/NewsandEvents/Portals/_default/Skins/SimTwo/includes/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css` is showing 404 but `http://www.sim-one.ca/Portals/_default/Skins/SimTwo/includes/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css`

You can just use links like :
`/Portals/_default/Skins/SimTwo/includes/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css` in order to fix this in skin file or use `<%= SkinPath %>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding return false; on your event after calling the dnnModal.show()